# Magento transnational mails not working

Tags: magento-1.9

when I placed order in magento newsletter subscription mail receive instead of receiving order confirmation mail. please help Thanks.

Comment: go to System->Configuration->Sales Email->Order and check is it enable?

Comment: it is already enable.